# Why use a semaphore for each processor in a spooling simulation

Tags: concurrency, semaphore

I'm working on a project that simulates multiple processors handling commands and queuing strings to be printed via one spooler.

There are up to ten processors, each executing a series of jobs that have "compute" and "print" statements.  Compute is just a mathematical process to take up time to simulate other work, while print transfers a short string to the spooler to be printed.  There is one spooler, with one printer hooked up to the spooler.  Each processor will handle a number of jobs before termination, all print statements from a specific job on a specific processor should print together (no interleaving of printing from individual jobs), and the spooler should never be blocked on a process that is computing.

I generally understand how to code this using semaphore and mutex structures, but a statement in the specifications confused me:

> Try to maximize the concurrency of your system. (You might consider using
>   an array of semaphores indexed by processor id.)

Is there a specific advantage I'm missing to using a semaphore for each individual process?

If further clarification is needed, let me know--I tried to describe the problem in a concise way.

EDIT:
Another possibly important piece: each processor has a buffer that can hold up to ten strings for sending to the spooler.  Could the sempahores for each process be for waiting when the buffer is full?

EDIT 2:
A job can contain multiple compute and print statements mixed in with each other:
Job 1
Calculate 4
Print Foo
Calculate 2
Print Bar
End Job

Print statements within a job should all be printed in order (Foo and Bar should be printed sequentially without a print from another job/processor in between).

Comment: I miss read the quote.  It seems it is leaning more toward a technique of lock-striping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important information is here:

> (no interleaving of printing from individual jobs),

This implies a `new Semaphore(1)` (if you are using Java).

And

> and the spooler should never be blocked on a process that is
>   computing.

If you had a semaphore that accepts one party this last piece would not be satisfied.  An executing processor should not have to wait for another to complete, it can be done in parallel.

You can do this by creating a striped set of semaphores.  You have it indexed by the processor ID so that each thread/processor would run without interleaving but without waiting for other processors to complete.

```
Semaphore[] semaphores = new Semaphore[Number_of_proessors];
//initialize all semaphore indexes

semaphores[Process.id].acquire();

//work    

semaphores[Process.id].release();
```

Comment: Does edit 2 change your answer at all?  I apologize for any clarification issues.

Comment: @jandjorgensen It doesnt. I re-read what I wrote and it seemed as if I was calling the process of lock-striping as coarse grained (where it absolutely isn't).  What I had meant was that it was eliminating the act of a shared coarse lock and making them per-processor fine grained locking.

Comment: Ok, so is the advantage in that the blocking of a process in this case results from only that thread's need for a resource versus a non-striped semaphore would cause each process to wait on every other process's remaining needs?